# Ruby: Setting output separator for IO object

Tags: ruby

(Crossposting note: This question has already been asked at https://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/6879239 without getting a response)

From the documentation of IO#print:

"Writes the given object(s) to ios. ... If the output record separator
(`$\`) is not nil, it will be appended to the output."

If I take this literally, it means that I can only have a single output
separator (`$\`) for all streams. But in general, I have several streams
open for writing. How can I set different output separators for them?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is one global record separator and you can't set it per-stream.

Answer (score 0):

I have been reading about Procs and here is an idea (perhaps far-fetched). Could you package the different values of `$\` that you need into Procs (which maintain their creation context)? You could do your stream processing inside the block belonging to the Proc.

```
def stream_1_proc
  $\ = <value1>
  return Proc.new { puts $\ }
end

def stream_2_proc
  $\ = <value2>
  return Proc.new { puts $\ }
end

# it seems like this should NOT work because $\ is global,
# but it works for me in IRB
stream_1_proc.call # $\ = <value1>
stream_2_proc.call # $\ = <value2>
```

That solution is not DRY, but maybe instead you could pass an argument to a single function with the value for `$\` (but would `$\` get overwritten between calls?).

```
def stream_proc(output_separator)
  $\ = output_separator
  return Proc.new { puts $\ }
end
```

Comment: Yeah, that's a race condition. A nightmare to debug, I imagine.

Comment: Blocks close over their *lexical* environment. Variables starting with `$` aren't lexical variables, they are global variables. Global variables are called "global variables" because they are the same everywhere.